# C++ Find Algorithm: How do I find the last occurance of an element?

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator

I'd like to find the last element of an array that satisfies a given condition. In return I'd like either:

1. An iterator, such that I can use std::distance to find the distance between that iterator and the beginning of the vector, or
2. Directly have the position of said element returned.

**In general, what I'm trying to solve is**:
(i) Find the maximum element in the vector (max_element), and (ii), find the *first* occurrence of 0 before that max element.

So in the following example:

```
{0, 10, 20, 0, 5, 50, 0, 70, 10, 0} 
// Get max at position 7, return 0 at position 6
```

After using max_element from the algorithm header, I tried something like the below code snippet using reverse iterators.

```
auto Itr1 = std::max_element(vect.begin(), vect.end());
auto Itr2 = std::find(Itr1, vect.rend(), [](int i){return i == 0;});
```

Mixing reverse and forward iterators wasn't fun and didn't work. It seems like there should be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, not very elegant though, requires another vector that only has 0 in it:

```
std::vector<int> v1 { 0, 10, 20, 0, 5, 50, 0, 70, 10, 0 };
std::vector<int> v2 { 0 };

auto Itr1 = std::max_element(v1.begin(), v1.end());
auto Itr2 = std::find_end(v1.begin(), Itr1, v2.begin(), v2.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `make_reverse_iterator()` defined in header `<iterator>`.
Also note that the third argument which `find()` takes is value which is to be found.

```
    std::vector<int> A{ 0, 10, 20, 0, 5, 50, 0, 70, 10, 0 };
    auto itr1 = std::max_element(A.begin(), A.end());
    auto itr2 = std::find(std::make_reverse_iterator(itr1), A.rend(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Got wrong at first, 
I think you are looking for [reverse_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator)

```
int main()
{

  std::vector<int> vect{0, 10, 20, 0, 5, 50, 0, 70, 10, 0};
  auto Itr1 = std::max_element(vect.begin(), vect.end());
  auto Itr2 = find_if(std::make_reverse_iterator(Itr1), vect.rend(), [](int i){return i == 0;});

  std::cout<< vect.rend() - Itr2 - 1<<std::endl;
  return 0;

}
```